# Is Goku still pure-hearted?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super

This question could seem as an opinion based question, but let me try to explain why I think it is not. In Dragon Ball, Goku was supposed to be completely pure-hearted to be able to ride the Flying Nimbus, to the point he needed to have no bad intentions at all, otherwise he couldn't stand in the top of it, he had to be a sort of Super Saiyan Jesus. At some point in the Dragon Ball series, Vegeta emphasizes this by saying Goku never dared to kill someone (because of this).

But at some point after that, Goku indeed kills someone, that is kid Bu. With Piccolo before, someone could argue he didn't actually finished him because he immediately reincarnated or so, but this isn't the case of kid Buu. And now, in Dragon Ball Super, Goku is doing something different to what he always did. When someone threatened the Earth or the universe, no matter how strong he was, he at least tried to defeat him. But with the case of Zeno, he didn't even try. Someone could argue Zeno is so powerful that he knew he couldn't defeat him, but is Zeno that powerful? He isn't almighty because several Zenos were created by Trunks and Zamasu when messing with time, Zeno isn't unbelievably strong because he can't follow Dyspo's moves. At some point I thought this "destroying all universes" thing was a fake, but now the manga has shown that

> indeed Zeno destroys all universes permanently and the great priest doesn't care, he only acknowledges Zeno whims.

Why Goku didn't even try to defeat Zeno by training and merging with Vegeta or whatever, and he doesn't care much about all the universes which are being destroyed every time he defeats them? Is Goku still pure-hearted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well as far as at the end of DBZ, we can concluded that all of the saiyans including Vegeta are pure hearted. This is because one of the condition of the Super Saiyan God transformation was that 5 pure hearted Saiyans needed to come together and since the transformation worked, it can be concluded all of them are pure hearted post Z.

Secondly, The Omni king isn't powerful in terms of raw power. What makes him terrifying is his position and the ability to erase anything from existence. Even the angels and  the grand priest and of course the gods, the strongest beings of the universe bow down before him so what makes you think Vegito blue could stand up to him.

Goku on the other hand has no evil in him. The only reason for him wanting the tournament is his addiction to battle and at the same time his rather naive and careless nature could be considered at fault for the tournament of power.

However, it was implied that goku did actually do the other universes a favour(Although he didn't intend to) as Zeno was about to erase the rest of the universes with a lower mortal  ranking.

Comment: The last line was more of plot armor by the author to save Goku.